# How to force redrawing a group row in a NSOutlineView after it’s been expanded/collapsed

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

I tried calling `setNeedsDysplay:` and `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` but `drawBackgroundInRect:` and `drawSeparatorInRect:` are not called for the group row but for everything else

This is piece of code I have:

```
- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView didAddRowView:(NSTableRowView *)rowView forRow:(NSInteger)row {
    id prevItem = [outlineView itemAtRow:row - 1];
    if ([self outlineView:outlineView isGroupItem:prevItem]) {
        id view = [self outlineView:outlineView rowViewForItem:prevItem];
        if (view) {
            [view setNeedsDisplay:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

This is what I came up with:

```
- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView didRemoveRowView:(NSTableRowView *)rowView forRow:(NSInteger)row {
    // TODO: find a be a better way to repaint a node after it's been collapsed
    for (NSView *view in outlineView.subviews) {
        NSInteger testRow = [outlineView rowForView:view];
        if (testRow == row - 1) {
            id item = [outlineView itemAtRow:testRow];
            if ([(id)outlineView outlineView:outlineView isGroupItem:item]) {
                [view setNeedsDisplay:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView didAddRowView:(NSTableRowView *)rowView forRow:(NSInteger)row {
    // TODO: find a be a better way to repaint a node after it's been expanded
    for (NSView *view in outlineView.subviews) {
        NSInteger testRow = [outlineView rowForView:view];
        if (testRow == row - 1) {
            id item = [outlineView itemAtRow:testRow];
            if ([(id)outlineView outlineView:outlineView isGroupItem:item]) {
                [view setNeedsDisplay:YES];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...but it's too slow in some cases

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this did the trick:

```
- (void)outlineViewItemDidCollapse:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSInteger row = [_outlineView rowForItem:notification.userInfo[@"NSObject"]];
    NSView *rowView = [_outlineView rowViewAtRow:row makeIfNecessary:NO];
    [rowView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)outlineViewItemDidExpand:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSInteger row = [_outlineView rowForItem:notification.userInfo[@"NSObject"]];
    NSView *rowView = [_outlineView rowViewAtRow:row makeIfNecessary:NO];
    [rowView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Comment: Hi, your question's phrasing is identical to what I need - yet, you only redraw the same view - where I need to replace the NSTableCellView of my item's row when collapsed/expanded. For that -- your trick doesn't apply. If instead I use [_outlineView reloadItem:notification.userInfo[@"NSObject"]  reloadChildren:NO] my cell-view is indeed reloaded, but the whole outlineView hangs, and selection/collapsing/expanding stops working. Idea why?